# MySQL SQL Error more then 1 table select

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write an sql that checks up multiple tables,this is what I got:

```
UPDATE item_template SET BuyPrice = 0, SellPrice = 1 WHERE entry IN (SELECT item FROM npc_vendor WHERE entry IN (SELECT entry FROM creature WHERE area = 3998)));
```

Now my error is:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ')' at line 1

What may cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave Mroz mentioned, this query would be much more efficient if you used [multi-table update syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) with `JOIN`, something like this:

```
UPDATE item_template 
  inner join npc_vendor on npc_vendor.item = item_template.entry
  inner join creature on creature.entry = npc_vendor.entry
SET item_template.BuyPrice = 0, item_template.SellPrice = 1 
where creature.area = 3998;
```

Comment: Great,I just tested mine and it took more then 300 seconds to run.I am pretty novice into mysql :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two opening `(` and three closing `)`

Also, you should probably try to rewrite this with a `JOIN` instead of nested subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
UPDATE item_template SET BuyPrice = 0, SellPrice = 1 WHERE entry IN (SELECT item FROM npc_vendor WHERE entry IN (SELECT entry FROM creature WHERE area = 3998));
```

Comment: Thank you,seems I have to drink another coffee.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 1 too many closing parens.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE item_template SET BuyPrice = 0, SellPrice = 1 WHERE entry IN (SELECT item FROM npc_vendor WHERE entry IN (SELECT entry FROM creature WHERE area = 3998));
```

this is correct.you have added extra ')'

Answer (score 1):

you have one extra closing paranthese

```
    UPDATE item_template
SET BuyPrice = 0,
    SellPrice = 1
WHERE entry IN
    (SELECT item
     FROM npc_vendor
     WHERE entry IN
         (SELECT entry
          FROM creature
          WHERE area = 3998));
                         ^^^^^^^ Remove one ) here
```